# C# Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'dynamic' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, list, dynamic

Suppose I have a

```
List<dynamic> myList = new List<dynamic>();
```

Inside a class:

```
public class DynamicMixin : DynamicObject
{
    internal List<dynamic> myList= new List<dynamic>();

    public void AddInterface<T>(T _item) where T:class{
        Interfaces.Add(_item);
    }

    public override bool TryGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, object[] indexes, out object result)
    {
        if (myList.Contains((item)=>item.GetType().Equals(indexes[0].GetType())){
            /* do something */
        }
        return base.TryGetIndex(binder, indexes, out result);
    }

}
```

I'm trying to write
    myDynamicObject[typeof(IDisposable)]
So I would get the IDiposable object which belongs to myDynamicObject.

This line gives me an error:

```
if (myList.Contains((item)=>item.GetType().Equals(indexes[0].GetType())){
```

**Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'dynamic' because it is not a delegate type**

I'm able to do it by iterating through the list: 
But why I'm not capable of using `Contains` ?

Comment: That's a really interesting way of doing mix-ins in c#. I have a open source framework [impromptu-interface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) that can take a list of interfaces and makes a really lightweight proxy that inherits those interface and basically wraps a bunch of callsite bindings that forward to a DynamicObject. You might be interested in it.

Comment: Very interesting your framework, jbtule. I'll dig into it for awhile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Becasue `Contains` is declared as:

```
public bool Contains(
    T item
)
```

You shoud use `Any(your lambda)`

Comment: Oh god, I completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 7):

`Contains()` expects an actual item (of type `dynamic` in your case) not a delegate, I think you want `Any()` :

```
 if (myList.Any( item => item.GetType().Equals(indexes[0].GetType()))
 {
```

Answer (score 2):

[`IEnumerable<T>.Contains()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx) does not have an overload that takes a lambda.